# How to get CGI variables?

Tags: urls, variables

I need to do two things:

1. Add a CGI variable (say filter=21) to the current query and make a link to this modified URL.
2. Fetch the value of CGI variable "filter".

How to do that in WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, these aren't CGI variables, they're **query string arguments**.

WordPress, by default, will remove any query arguments that it doesn't recognize.  So you need to register them with WordPress and then pull them back out of the query.

**First, add your new query variable:**

```
function wpa_48528_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'filter';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa_48528_vars' );
```

**Now, get the data back out:**

```
function wpa_48528_get_filter() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'filter', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        return $wp_query->query_vars['filter'];
    }

    return '';
}
```